# Last login time not correct on profile

Tags: support, recent-activity

It's happened to me twice now. When I opened up my profile, I saw this:

> last login  35 seconds ago

But in reality I didn't login. Why is it saying that?

Comment: and now i saw 19 mins ago when i only logged in for 4 minutes!

Comment: Meh. My profile hasn't seen any activity from me in 11 hours. Apparently, i left a comment then; guess i might as well do that again.

Answer (score 1):

Perharps your browser is having a bad case of cookie indigestion?